# install PerformanceAnalytics on R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28)

Tags: r, anaconda, performanceanalytics

I tried to install PerformanceAnalytics on R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28), and I get a series of error messages. The most meaningful seemed to be that PerformanceAnalytics was not compatible with my version of R (which is the most up to date one). Then it came up with:

> ```
> make: *** [momentF.o] Error 1
> ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘PerformanceAnalytics’
> ```

I happen to have version R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06) installed on my computer and it installs correctly with this, however, I would like to understand what is going on.

I am not sure if the problem is not connected to anaconda. (I am using the later version of R through anaconda).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible if you try to install it from github?

```
library(devtools)
install_github("cran/PerformanceAnalytics")
```

I use RStudio as a more robust solution.

Comment: I was thinking of trying to install an old version of RStudio (there is this option) ...but I have doubts that this will go somewhere

Comment: No there is not any need I believe to go to older version. Have you installed Rtools34 ?

Comment: I think I have reached a "solution." Basically, to stop using anaconda. There is something I dont understand. My anaconda has 3.4.2, however, on the cloud.r-project.org... there is no 3.4.2 ... I installed, 3.4.3... it seems ok now. This is 3-4 h work down the drain... thanks for getting my mind going

Comment: @user8369515 Happy to help.